# Regex: Insert text after file type extension

Tags: jquery, regex, string

I have a string like this, that is a list of file names;

```
mouse.gifcat.jpgdog.pngwolf.tga...
```

It has no spaces, and they're different file formats. I can guarantee the extension will always be 3 characters long.

I'd like to insert " | " between the files in this text line to get mouse.gif | cat.jpg...

I could just use replace(/.ext/g, ".ext | ") for each different extension I'm expecting, but I'd like something multipurpose.

What would the regex be?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
.replace(/(\....)/g,"$1|")
```

That is, match a literal `.` with `\.`, followed by any three characters with `...`, capturing that group with parentheses so that you can use it in the replacement string as `$1`.

EDIT: Or actually you don't need the parens if you use `$&` instead of `$1`:

```
x.replace(/\..../g,"$&|")
```

Though either way it will add a `|` at the end of the string too, so perhaps:

```
.replace(/\..../g,"$&|").slice(0,-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
.replace(/(\....)(.)/g, '$1|$2')
```